# Tail biting convolution encoder

Tags: communication, digital-communications, encoder, decoder, standard

I understand how encoders and decoders work, but what are theses values?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help your understanding: -

[image]

[Octal to decimal converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/octal-to-decimal.html).

Comment: But note that it's insane to convert binary to octal by way of decimal.  Just take groups of 3 bits.